# Съзжает иконка если появляется вторая строка в элементе списка

Tags: html, css

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  padding: 100px;
  background: #929292;
  font-size: 100%;
  font-family: "Arial";
}

input {
  font-size: 1em;
}

ol.tree {
  padding-left: 30px;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: -15px;
}

li label {
  padding-left: 37px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: url("https://www.thecssninja.com/demo/css_tree/folder-horizontal.png") no-repeat 15px 2px;
  display: block;
}

li input {
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  position: absolute;
  left: -0.5em;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

li input+ol {
  height: 1em;
  margin: -16px 0 0 -44px;
  background: url("https://www.thecssninja.com/demo/css_tree/toggle-small-expand.png") no-repeat 40px 0;
}

li input+ol>li {
  display: none;
  margin-left: -14px !important;
  padding-left: 1px
}

li.file {
  margin-left: -1px !important;
}

li.file a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 21px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: url("https://www.thecssninja.com/demo/css_tree/document.png") no-repeat 0 0;
}

li input:checked+ol {
  height: auto;
  margin: -21px 0 0 -44px;
  padding: 25px 0 0 80px;
  background: url("https://www.thecssninja.com/demo/css_tree/toggle-small.png") no-repeat 40px 5px;
}

li input:checked+ol>li {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 0.063em;
}

li input:checked+ol>li:first-child {
  margin: 0 0 0.125em;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Меню</title>

</head>

<body>
  <ol class="tree">
    <li>
      <label for="two">Двухстрочный <br> вариант</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="two" />
      <ol>
        <li>
          <label for="menu-1-1">menu-1-1</label>
          <input type="checkbox" id="menu-1-1" />
          <ol>
            <li>
              <label for="menu-1-1-1">menu-1-1-1</label>
              <input type="checkbox" id="menu-1-1-1" />
              <ol>
                <li class="file"><a href="">menu-1-1-1-1-1</a></li>
                <li class="file"><a href="">menu-1-1-1-1-2</a></li>
                <li class="file"><a href="">menu-1-1-1-1-3</a></li>
              </ol>
            </li>

          </ol>
        </li>

      </ol>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label for="one">Однострочный вариант</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="one" />
      <ol>
        <li>
          <label for="menu-2-1">menu-2-1</label>
          <input type="checkbox" id="menu-2-1" />
          <ol>
            <li>
              <label for="menu-2-1-1">menu-2-1-1</label>
              <input type="checkbox" id="menu-2-1-1" />
              <ol>
                <li class="file"><a href="">menu-2-1-1-1</a></li>
                <li class="file"><a href="">menu-2-1-1-2</a></li>
                <li class="file"><a href="">menu-2-1-1-3</a></li>
                <li class="file"><a href="">menu-2-1-1-4</a></li>
                <li class="file"><a href="">menu-2-1-1-5</a></li>
              </ol>
            </li>
          </ol>
</body>

</html>
```

**текст, выделенный жирным шрифтом**

Comment: уточните, какая иконка и где съезжает? открыл ваш пример, пооткрывал папочки, вроде все на своих местах

Comment: Там где пункт двухстрочный вариант плюсик съезжает на вторую строку, а мне надо, чтобы он остался на первой